# How can I vary voltage across USB & detect varying voltage across usb using programming in C or C++

Tags: c++, c

.
  I was thinking over to send some data from my PC to some other PC 
  using Radio Frequency (88-108 MHz) . Radio transmitter for sending 
  & detector for receiving using some customized protocols.
  '1'-frequency & '0'- no frequency (at constant frequency). 
  Here 1 & 0 are binary data converted from original data to be sent .

The question is : - 
How can I vary voltage across USB & detect varying voltage across usb using programming in C or C++ .

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is it you are really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

You can't - USB is a digital connection and you have no control of the voltages it employs. You can however use USB to communicate with another suitable device which would control whatever voltages you require. May I suggest you take a look at [Arduino](http://arduino.cc)?

Answer (score 2):

By finding (or building) and installing a piece of custom hardware and a matching device driver, and following the instructions that come with them.

USB itself provides power and a digital signal, all based on 5 volt levels [power 5V, data 3.3V]. You can't  control those voltages. You can get a small plug-in USB board which provides voltage control.

USB is generally accessible only at the device driver level, which means operating system only. With a suitable piece of hardware comes a driver that you can access from C/C++ via an O/S API call. The sample code to do that comes with the software.

Definitely look for an electronics hobbyist forum rather than this one. This problem has been solved so many times...

Comment: usb data signals are **not 5V**

Comment: @vlad_tepesch: I said 'based on'. Precisely defining the values is too complicated. Hope the edit is better.

Answer (score 0):

You need a specialized DAC and ADC units to generate and acquire the specific analog signals to interact with your RF hardware. The USB controller hardware does not allow you to interact directly with the ADC and DAC units on the hardware.

As an alternative from the software side you can use:

- specialized hardware, ie, [Arduino](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/InterfacingWithHardware#adcdac) or some other microcontroller, or some [custom circuitry](http://www.amsat.org/amsat/articles/g3ruh/109.html).
- your [soundcard](http://www.zeitnitz.de/Christian/scope_en) as a general purpose ADC and DAC,
- or use your serial port as a poor's man ADC/DAC.

Note that since you plan on using the commercial FM radio spectrum you are limited to something like 8k-10k bits/s.